# Spinner numbers probability

Tags: probability

[image: The spinner]

This is an unbiased spinner with ten numbered sectors. Four of the sectors are shaded. When spun, the probability of stopping at any one of the sectors is equal.

> (a) If the pointer is spun once, find the probability that the number is a prime number OR the sector is shaded

My answer:
$$P = 5/10 + 4/10 = 9/10$$

> (b) If the pointer is spun once, find probability that the number is even AND the sector is shaded

My answer:
$$P= 4/10 \times 4/10 = 4/25$$

However, both of my answers are wrong and I don't quite understand why. Can I get help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Be careful about double-counting regions.  You should only count the region which is the shaded $3$ once (in (a), you are counting it twice - once for being prime and once for being shaded).  It is much better to count the number of regions that satisfy the conditions and divide that by $10$.

Answer (score 1):

For this problem, you cannot use the addition rule because the events are not *mutually exclusive*: that is, it is possible that a sector is shaded AND the number in it is prime. (An example of mutually exclusive events would be, either it is raining or it is not raining, it cannot be both at the same time.) You cannot use the multiplication rule either as the conditions mentioned are not independent; e.g., the probability of being shaded is different for primes, odd numbers, etc. So, it is better to count them by hand.

For part (a), there are 8 sectors which either are shaded or contain a prime number. Thus, the probability of getting one of these is $8/10$.

For part (b), there is only one sector which is shaded and contains an even number. Thus, the probability is $1/10$.

(Extra: if you really want to use the addition rule, you can add the probability that a sector is shaded to the probability that a sector contains a prime number, and subtract the probability that both conditions occur together. You need to subtract because the case in which both occur is counted once in the first probability, and again in the second. This gives the same answer. If you really want to use the multiplication rule, well, you can't.)

Comment: I realize some time has passed since this answer was posted, but: Your first paragraph seems a *little* imprecise: You cannot use addition because they're not mutually exclusive; you cannot use multiplication because they're not independent.

Comment: @BrianTung Edited. Never too late to fix things :)